# Determinant of a $5\times 5$ matrix using properties

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Apparently the determinant of the following matrix can be transformed into the determinant of a $2\times 2$ matrix multiplied by a scalar. Would anyone show me how?

$$ \left( \begin{array}{ccccc} 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
0 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{array} \right)$$

Comment: You can change rows of the determinant to make it diagonal but keep in mind the change in sign.

Comment: Why no just permute the columns until you have a diagonal matrix? Each permutation changes the sign of the determinant and the determinant of a diagonal matrix is the product of the diagonals.

Comment: So $\det(A)=\pm 5!$, without any $2\times 2$ manipulation.

Comment: Clearly I'm not up to date with my introduction to linear algebra course since I didn't know about the laplacian expansion or that I could permute and multiply the diagonal... thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the rest that permutations of rows and columns is sufficient.

Another way is by doing Laplace expansion.

\begin{align}  \begin{vmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
0 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{vmatrix} &= \begin{vmatrix} 
2 & 0  & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0  & 3 & 0 \\
0 & 0  & 0 & 4 \\
0 & 5  & 0 & 0\end{vmatrix} \\ &=  2\begin{vmatrix} 
 0  & 3 & 0 \\
 0  & 0 & 4 \\
 5  & 0 & 0\end{vmatrix} \\ &= 
2(5)\begin{vmatrix} 
    3 & 0 \\
    0 & 4 \\
   \end{vmatrix} \end{align}